# If validation is true then ignore the others that are on the same property (JSR 303)

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I have a field that has three annotations validation

```
@MyCustomValidation.List(
{ 
        @MyCustomValidation(
        fieldName = "hasAddress",
        fieldValue = "false",
        dependFieldName = "address")

})
public class Example {
@NotEmpty
@Length(min=3,max=100)
String address;

Boolean hasAddress;
```

I want to know know how to hibernate validator can ignore other validations when `myCustomerValidation` returns true in certain situations.

In this case, if and only if `hasAddress` field has **true** value should be validated the length of the `address`, otherwise it should not do any validation

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Put all 3 conditions in one custom validator.

Comment: I also thought that, but I want to avoid having to implement validations that already exist.

Comment: In your example, why is there a separate flag "hasAddress"? Isn't the fact that "address" is null or not null indicator enough whether the address field should be validated? Constraint validators should consider null as a valid value in general, so such flag seems not needed (this is not to rebut the idea in general, just trying to understand your use case a bit better).